# CGIDEV2 & Public Webpage (IBM Iseries / AS400)

Tags: cgi, ibm-midrange, rpgle

Good Afternoon,

Perhaps this is a silly question, but I'm wondering if someone could help to point me in the right direction as I'm not even sure where to start.

I am starting to become adept at using CGIDEV2 tool to create a webpage using RPGLE. Currently all of my applications are internal, if a user wants to access them they need to be on the company network or VPN (outside of office).

How feasible is it to create an application that is public? My biggest fear is opening up our AS400 to potential hacker attacks, viruses, etc by making an application available publicly (no need to be on our network). I also can't even wrap my mind around how that would work while still being able to communicate back to the server from the client.

If anyone has done anything like this and can offer some feedback and perhaps point me to an article, guide, or video it would be much appreciated.

Thanks again

Comment: this isn't a coding question...this is networking/infrastructure/security question

Comment: Agree with Charles. Moving to public requires security planning, new layers to split ibm i servers from web server architecture, firewall measures, probably load balancing planning, and more...not a little step. A management decision.